# The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

```dart
import 'package:Connectify/widgets/auth/chats/message_bubble.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Messages extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
      // future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
      // future: FirebaseAuth.instanceFor.currentUser(),
      builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
        if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chat')
              .orderBy(
                'createdAt',
                descending: true,
              ).snapshots(),
          builder: (ctx, chatSnapShot) {
            if (chatSnapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            final chatDocs = chatSnapShot.data.docs;
            return ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              itemCount: chatDocs.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
                chatDocs[index]['text'],
                chatDocs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data.uid,
                key: chatDocs[index].docsId,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My code is given above when I am trying to call Firebase.instance.currentUser on future builder it is giving me error:

**The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.**

when i am trying to do with without paranthesis

Firebase.instance.currentUser

it gives error like this:

**The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future'**

I dont know how to tackle this, if anyone knows feel free to answer

Comment: `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` doesn't return `Future` type. Return type of `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` is `User`. If you want to wrap it to `Future`, use `Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser())`.

Comment: @fartem thanks fartem that solves my problem..❤

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentUser` getter returns a `User` so you don't need a `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
import 'package:Connectify/widgets/auth/chats/message_bubble.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat')
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (ctx, chatSnapShot) {
        if (chatSnapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        final chatDocs = chatSnapShot.data.docs;
        return ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          itemCount: chatDocs.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
            chatDocs[index]['text'],
            chatDocs[index]['userId'] == user.uid,
            key: chatDocs[index].docsId,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```